# Shift + rotate is initiated, rotate object by 15° steps (FabricJS)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an editor working with FabricJS. The goal is that I need to make an object to rotate each time by 15 degrees (in a way that if the object is on 3 degrees, it will go to 15 (not 18) and each step must be 15.
Currently I've managed to achieve to rotate by 15 degrees but it happens only once.

```
textObj.on('rotating', function (rotEvtData) {

     if (event.shiftKey == true && event.type == 'mousemove') {

         textObj.rotate(15);

     }

});
```

FabricJS version is 1.7.17

Comment: you should use `snapAngle` property